# How can i share a token validation function with redirects?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to protect my pages to ensure that if user only can access them if he is authenticated.
What i am doing is to check if the user is authenticated, if not i redirect to login page, if he is authenticated I check if the local stored Token is still valid, if it is nothing will happen. If it is expired, I will logout which removes info from local storage and redirects to login.
So my question is, is there a better way to do this and also how can I put this code into a function which can be called by all my pages which need to be protected.

```
  ionViewWillEnter(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated().pipe(
      tap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login')
        }
        else {
          this.auth.checkTokenValidity().subscribe(() => { }, err => {
            if (err.error.error === 'TokenExpiredError') {
              this.auth.logout(true).subscribe(() => {
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login');
              });
            }
          })
        }
      })
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use Angular's [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access). They pretty much work in the way you explained. You have a class that you define with a single function `canActivate` that is responsible for determining whether a user can enter the route.

In your case this is where you'd add token validation. Then in your route definition you just add it to the canActivate array to any route you want to guard. I usually create a top level route that is guarded and then any children to that route are automatically guarded.